# How to create a ddd aggregate and update other aggregate with its reference in the same transaction?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

I would like to ask about a problem I have using DDD in the implementation of a game.

I have a situation where, based on a message the system receives, a new aggregate for a player is created. The problem comes from the fact this new aggregate has to be referenced by another aggregate (a table aggregate) using its id. This second aggregate keeps a value object with information about the player at the table like his position or colour chosen. The player aggregate stores players actions because, depending on the number of players and actions issued by them, the table aggregate could become massive and the lock contention at the database would be too costly if I keep everything on table. For the player to be able to join the table, some validations have to be passed first, like colour not taken, maximum number of players already reached or games that the player has been inactive, that's why this value object is stored at table with info from the players.

So, based on this, I only create the player aggregate when he issues the first action to be stored outside the table. The problem with that is that table could hold value objects referencing an aggregate that hasn't been created yet which makes the code look ugly as it forces it to check for null references. The other option, that is creating first the player aggregate, also breaks the design as the validations to create a player happens on the table first. Because of the concurrent nature of the system, validating first on table to then create the player aggregate and then, on receiving the event from the creation, update the table, could cause many race conditions. The only thing I can think of is updating two aggregates in the same transaction but that goes against DDD rules.

Is there any nice solution to this? I guess in the end this is going to be related to the design but I cannot think of any way it could work without introducing performance issues.

Thanks.

Comment: What about something like `player = table.newPlayer(...); playerRepository.save(player); tableRepository.save(table);` where `Table` just adds a VO to an internal collection. Here you do not modify two aggregates in the same transaction, since player is just created, not modified. Therefore, no contention can exist on the player instance.

Comment: Could you actually do that? I thought the whole thing about not modifying two aggregates in the same transaction included the creation as well. Even that wouldn't work in my case as Players are not removed from the PlayerRepository once they leave the Table. I would have to check as doing that I don't know if I would break something else. There is another requirement to store shortcuts for Players but that may be in another bounded context so it could still be safe to remove a Player after he leaves. But I would like to know first if updating and creating at the same time is valid in ddd.

Comment: Yes, I belive it's valid since there's no increase of the risk of concurrency conflicts. E.g. wheter you only modify the `Table` aggregate or that you modify the `Table` aggregate and you create a `Player` object and save it doesn't change anything in terms of concurrency conflicts. Concurrency conflicts are the main reason to avoid **modifying** many aggregates in a single transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's not an easy subject really understanding DDD and what is allowed and what is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As often, part of your issues may be solved by looking at them from a domain and ubiquitous language perspective.

- Udi Dahan has an [excellent article](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/) about how Aggregate Roots don't appear out of thin air but as a result of a domain action that must be a first class ubiquitous language citizen. In your case, Player could be created not by the application service but closest to the domain source, by the `Table` AR.

  Note that I don't necessarily advocate holding full references to other Roots like in Udi's example, but you could replace that with `Table.ReceivePlayer(...)` returning the newly created player, which can then be added to `PlayerRepository` by the application service. Since `Player` doesn't play the role of an Aggregate Root (i.e. single entry point to modifications and invariant enforcement) but that of a simple Entity in that scenario, you could legitimately wrap all that in a single transaction.
- The forces that drive Aggregate modelling are basically true invariants, concurrency and performance. To justify how you modelled yours, you state that *the table aggregate could become massive and the lock contention at the database would be too costly if I keep everything on table*.

  I think it would pay off to explore a bit more what this contention would really be and putting domain terms behind it, enriching your ubiquitous language. Is a table massively concurrent ? How so ? Does the game have mutable shared state that players modify ? Do players need to make decisions based on other players' moves, introducing some kind of bias if concurrent actions are taken in the mean time ? How does all that translate in domain terms ? What does the additional `Player` aggregate bring you ?

  In terms of performance, what would a massive `Table` aggregate look like and how would it affect the system ?
- The "no transaction spanning multiple aggregates" rule is just a corollary of approaching Aggregates as consistency boundaries, it's not set in stone. It doesn't make sense to craft small, independently consistent aggregates and pack a ton of modifications to multiple of them in a single transaction, because you create unneeded contention, and potential concurrency issues ensue. But in a scenario where no concurrency problems exist beyond those of the sole `Table` AR, and this is certainly the case with creation since no-one else is aware of the Player being added, it's just as if you had only modified one Aggregate and the rule doesn't really hold any more.

  If you respect the rule in the 99% modification cases but don't in the 1% creation cases, you're still in the lines.

Comment: Regarding the questions about the ubiquitous language, I have thought about that several times and the points where the system could suffer from performance problems I think are well identified. What I may have failed to do is thinking about the proper names for it and how it should work.

The contention comes from the fact bets cannot be all store in the same aggregate. Doing that would lead to a massive Table as I said as there may be hundreds and Players may place Bets at the same time. But what this second aggregate should reflect is this storage so it could be called PlayerBetsBook

Comment: Following on that, I reckon now that this second aggregate, doing it this way, should be created and removed with the Player. That would solved the problem of referencing something not yet created as this wouldn't happen anymore. Creating it in the same transaction is not an option though. Even not breaking any DDD rule, I'm using MongoDB which doesn't help when dealing with transactionality. So I'll stick to the lazy creation, adding removal when Player leaves to solve my design problem. 
Thanks for the explanation, it has been really helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. Now I understand why this second Aggregate -- perfect illustration of why you should always describe the context as much as possible in a Q :) Turns out your implementation is close to the "split hot aggregate" strategy : http://www.jefclaes.be/2014/11/splitting-hot-aggregates.html. Do you have any "reconcile PlayerBetsBook with Table" operation happening at spaced out moments in time, like in that blog post ?

Comment: Yes, I have something similar. At the end of the game, I have to calculate who win what based on the result so I have to iterate through the list of PlayersBets for players sitting at the table. Once that's done, I remove all bets and a new game starts out. So at that point it's easier having everything on table as I wouldn't have to go to the database once per player but that wouldn't be performant enough during the game.